# Dash using local bootstrap stylesheet changes behavior

Tags: python, css, bootstrap-4, plotly-dash

I have download a bootstrap theme css stylesheet from [bootswatch](https://bootswatch.com/) and placed it in the assets folder of my app. The app is able to find the stylesheet as when I make minor changes in the stylesheet (e.g. increasing fontsize) this is showing up in my app.

Now I found out that not all parts of a bootstrap theme are working properly anymore after changing to the local stylesheet:

- Checkbox menus appear to be different than displayed before when I was using the external stylesheet from the same theme
- CardDecks do now display vertically instead of horizontally

Am I missing a part of the bootstrap layout? The stylesheet I am using is copied from [here](https://bootswatch.com/5/flatly/bootstrap.css).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem isn't the way you've included the styles, but the styles themselves (different versions).

There seems to be an incompatibility with [the `Bootswatch v5.0.1` stylesheet you linked](https://bootswatch.com/5/flatly/bootstrap.css) and some of the dash bootstrap components (flatly) styles.

Let's look at the styles dash bootstrap components has available:

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

# Find themes available through dash_bootstrap_components
print(dir(dbc.themes)) # ['BOOTSTRAP', 'CERULEAN', 'COSMO', 'CYBORG', 'DARKLY', 'FLATLY', 'GRID', 'JOURNAL', 'LITERA', 'LUMEN', 'LUX', 'MATERIA', 'MINTY', 'PULSE', 'SANDSTONE', 'SIMPLEX', 'SKETCHY', 'SLATE', 'SOLAR', 'SPACELAB', 'SUPERHERO', 'UNITED', 'YETI', '_BOOTSWATCH_BASE', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']

# Find FLATLY theme url
print(dbc.themes.FLATLY) # https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.5.2/flatly/bootstrap.min.css

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.FLATLY])
```

So dash bootstrap components version `0.12.0` works with bootswatch flatly version `4.5.2` (And others most likely, but I have only tested these versions).

I compared the diff between the `5.0.1` and `4.5.2` styles and found that the `5.0.1` version doesn't have any `.card-deck` styles, but the `4.5.2` version does, which explains the `CardDeck` component not looking correct.

I recommend you to just use the `dbc.themes.FLATLY` theme to ensure compatibility with the bootstrap dash components and add extra styles as needed.

To reiterate the problem is not caused by using local stylesheets in the `assets` directory instead of `external_stylesheets`. Both these approaches work. Choose whatever approach you prefer.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but i want to use a custom boostrap sheet made with https://bootstrap.build/app. Putting it in the assets folder doesn't work. Dash still loads the stylesheet from bootstrap cdn event though i didn't put "external_stylesheet" parameter